# In a lattice, does $x \vee y \leq x\vee z$ and $x \wedge y \leq x\wedge z$ imply $y\leq z$?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a lattice and $x,y,z\in L$.

If $y \leq z$, then clearly $x\vee y \leq x\vee z$ and $x\wedge y \leq x\wedge z$.

Now I wonder about the reverse direction.
In general, $x\vee y \leq x\vee z$ does not imply $y \leq z$ (take for example $x = 1$ in a lattice with 1). Neither does $x\wedge y \leq x\wedge z$.

But what about taking both those conditions together?
Does $x \vee y \leq x\vee z$ and $x \wedge y \leq x\wedge z$ together imply $y\leq z$?

My feeling is that the answer should be "yes", but so far I've failed to rigorously prove it.

If necessary, we may assume that the lattice under consideration is modular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. For a counterexample, take $N_5 = \{a,b,b',c,d\}$, with $a<b<b'<d$, and $a<c<d$. We have $d = c \vee b' \leq c \vee b = d$, and $a = c \wedge b' \leq c \wedge b = a$, but $b' > b$.

Actually the condition you stated seems to be equivalent to distributivity (and therefore imply modularity). $N_5$ isn't distributive, hence the counterexample.

Comment: The other 5-element non-distributive lattice (elements $0,x,y,z,1$ with $0\leq$ everything and everything $\leq1$ and $x,y,z$ pairwise incomparable) is another counterexample. Since every non-distributive lattice has a sublattice isomorphic to this one or to $N_5$, the "seems to be" in the answer can be upgraded to "is".

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me! Seems that the picture in my mind was completely wrong. Maybe because I just wanted this property to be true.